# firebase shows users count = 0 & event count > 0?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

there is some thing weird in my fribase console events page, it looks like this:
[image]

you can see that count > 0, that's mean there is some one triggered those event.

but in the other side you see that users = 0 , that's mean no one has triggered those events.

how come ?

**EDIT:**

I've contacted firbase support, here is the response:

```
There you go. I think that is the issue.

Please note that, quoting from the docs -  Custom parameters are not represented directly in your Analytics reports, but they can be used as filters in audience definitions that can be applied to every report.
```

i don't understand what's "not represented directly" mean ! why i have other custom events with users > 0 ?

Comment: david, it is possible to log events from background without having an active user. From the names of your events it seems that this should have some user engagement. Do you see active users? Might be your app is not correctly instrumented to report user engagement. 
Is this Android or iOS app?
Few things to check:
- Enable Firebase Analytics debug logging Look for errors in your logcat/xcore logs. 
- User engagement is reported with _e and _s events. If you don't see them when you foreground and background the app then your app is not correctly instrumented and this results in 0 users.

Comment: Are you applying any filters in this report?  Your screenshot doesn't capture the filter control.

Comment: david, can you enable debug logging and post logs? Its difficult to debug an issue without context.

Comment: @SteveGanem thank you for your comment. no i don't

Comment: @djabi , thank you for your comments. - this is an ios app , - this custom events so it's logged in foreground. - yes i see active users for other events. - i will enable debug mode and let you know